# Can we have a cursor on mathematical functions

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a sql cursor on a sum of sum.

```
CURSOR DATA_CURSOR IS
SELECT SUM(A)+SUM(B) FROM DATA_TABLE
```

I guess that may not be the correct way to do it.... how do I create it and how to fetch it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name the new column you created in the query e.g.:

```
CURSOR DATA_CURSOR IS
SELECT SUM(A)+SUM(B) AS SUM_AB
FROM DATA_TABLE
```

Comment: how do i fetch it? if i do 

    OPEN DATA_CURSOR;
    FETCH DATA_CURSOR INTO CURSOR_REC;  
    WHILE DATA_CURSOR%FOUND LOOP
       INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE (sum_ab) VALUES CURSOR_REC.sum_ab);

that will be an error, right?